# How can I see which of my iPhone apps support Siri Shortcuts?

Tags: ios, siri, shortcuts-app

Is there an easy way to see which of the apps I have installed on my iPhone support **Shortcuts**?

At the moment, I'm going one by one through each app in **Settings** and tapping through to **Siri & Search** to see if **Shortcuts** are supported. There has got to be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Shortcuts app and tap in the search bar. Scroll down the options like scripting, favourites, and content types, you should see all useable apps.

The suggestion can be seen in Settings-> Siri and Search-> all shortcuts. This lists some possible candidates for suggestions.

Comment: Ah right, the second option is closest to what I was looking for. Thanks!